# How to properly combine POSIXct objects with NULL in R?

Tags: r, posixct

When using R's primitive `c` function, combining the current datetime with `NULL` gives:

```
> class(c(NULL,Sys.time()))
[1] "numeric"
```

But when passing NULL last:

```
> class(c(Sys.time(),NULL))
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Is this intended? The documentation for `c` reads:
"The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression." but there is no mention of order being relevant.

Is there a better (more consistent) way to combine objects of class `POSIXct` with `NULL` into a vector? Or should one always explicitly test for `NULL` and handle it as a seperate case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `c` acts as an S3 generic, and there is a `POSIXct` method for it:

```
> c.POSIXct
function (..., recursive = FALSE) 
.POSIXct(c(unlist(lapply(list(...), unclass))))
<bytecode: 0x000001ab3e6efe58>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

(S3 methods dispatch on the class of the first argument, so `c(POSIXct, NULL)` will call `c.POSIXct`, whereas `c(NULL, POSIXct)` will call the default method.)